# Initializing an Escrow with NFT

Tags: nft

initializing an escrow. Just wondering if just sending an NFT can initialize an escrow or if we need both users interacting with escrow program to init. I want to be able to have an escrow initialize with just an NFT being sent so that users can see what tickets are open to rent

Answer (score 1):

You you transfer the NFT to a token account owned by a PDA.

```
    #[account(
        seeds = [
            AUTHORITY_PREFIX.as_bytes(),
        ],
        bump
    )]
    pub authority: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = payer,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = authority,
    )]
    pub mint_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
```

Now, you can use the `authority` account from within the program to transfer to token back to someone else.